# Lombok in imported Maven Module

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I have following maven structure:

```
parent-module
|-model-module
|-model-contributor-module
```

In `model-module` I have entities that annotated with `@lombok.Data`. When I make `mvn clean install` on `model-module` everything is ok. Second inner module `model-contributor-module` contains `model-module` in dependencies. When I try to do the same build on `model-contributor-module`, I receive an error `cannot find symbol`.

`pom.xml` for `model-module`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And `pom.xml` for `model-contributor-module`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
.....
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
....
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testDelombok</goal>
                        <goal>delombok</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How to fix these compilation errors?

```
[ERROR] /Users/superuser/Documents/workspace/project/test/src/main/java/com/company/services/impl/MyServiceImpl.java:[291,65] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUserId()
```

Comment: What compiler error can you post that too?

Comment: @soorapadman, I have added error message

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip`

Comment: @soorapadman the same result

Comment: Can you check that class `MyServiceImpl.java:[291,65]` 291 line whether you got any issue?

Comment: look like you don't  have `getUserId()`

Comment: @soorapadman Obviously he doesn't, he's using lombok `@Data`. The point is the other module can't see the generated stuff.

Comment: @NeilLocketz , do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing more than a guess. I haven't used the lombok-maven-plugin before. Does it create a separate artifact with the delombok-ed classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move that lombok dependency into the parent pom's dependencyManagement element so it can be inherited by the child modules. You have the plugin available in all modules, but it looks like the lombok dependency is only available in model-module.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   ...
   <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: and how to be with integration tests in `model-contributor-module` module?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you want to do integration tests, you can use maven-failsafe-plugin - see: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/